# displaying list of url images from firestore using gridview builder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, gridview

How do I display the first index when displaying a multiple/list of url images stored in firebase firestore? my model and helper are already good/working when fetching the current user posts. I think I do have a problem in displaying the images, rather the index 0 in the list.

```
static Stream<List<UserActivityModel>> readCurrentUser(String collectionPath, String subCollectionPath) {
    // will return a future
    final mainCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionPath);
    final userUidDocument = mainCollection.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    // will return a stream of snapshots
    final subCollection = userUidDocument .collection(subCollectionPath).snapshots();
    // return documents.
    return subCollection.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => UserActivityModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
```

and here is my code for my `StreamBuilder` GridView.Builder. I am having an error with this line:

```
final getImages = snapshot.data!["feelsImages"];
```

The error is:

> type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' gridview builder

```
StreamBuilder<List<UserActivityModel>>(
   stream: FirestoreHelper.readCurrentUser("posts", "posts"),
   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
         return const Center(
                       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                     ;
         }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return const Center(
                       child: Text("An error has occured while fetching users post."),
                       );
        }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // * this return below is working and fetching the number of posts of the current user.
        // return Text("current user posts, total of: ${snapshot.data!.length}.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,);
          // empty List
          List images = [];
          // I am trying to get the fetch images in the getImages
          final getImages = snapshot.data!["feelsImage"];
          // and I'll just loop it and add it.
          for(var img in getImages){
            images.add(img);
          }
                                            
          return GridView.builder(
          //itemCount: images.length,
          itemCount: images.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      ,
                       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                           return Container();
                              // * Then show display it here like:
                              // * images[0] to fetch the index 0 of the images inside the list.
                              
                              },
                              );
                              }
                              return Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
     }),
```

[image]